# Find groups of 3 consecutive numbers or more in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I know there are similar questions out there and I've tried really hard to implement them but I can't quite seem to make them work for my needs. I don't need to find **just** consecutive numbers. I need to find consecutive numbers of 3 or more and replace the middle numbers with a hyphen.

For example :

- arraylist contains `1,3,4,6,7,8,9`. The output should be `1,3,4,6-9`.
- or say the arraylist contains `1,3,4,5,7,8,9`. The output should be `1,3-5,7-9`.

The problem I'm having is writing the logic to differentiate between 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 or more digits, and groups of consecutive digits that are 3 or more. Thanks in advance for whatever help you can provide! :-)

Comment: Loop until the they are not consecutive and add the result into another ArrayList

Comment: Why is the second one not `2-5,7-9`?

Comment: You're right dave. Typo on my part. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty verbose way. This creates a new array list to which you will either add the number from the original or the range. It finds ranges by testing if the next entry is one greater than the current, and how long that trend continues. If there are at least 3 in a row, it adds the range and starts looking after the range. Otherwise, it just adds each number.

```
    List<String> altered = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        int start = i;
        int size = 1;
        int end = start;
        if(i<list.size()-2){
            end = start+1;
            while(list.get(end) == list.get(end-1)+1){
                size++;
                end++;
                if(end >= list.size())
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(size >=3){
            altered.add(list.get(start)+"-"+list.get(end-1));
            i = end-1;
        }
        else
            altered.add(""+list.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(altered);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I tried your code above and it works fine if there is one set of 3 or more consecutive numbers(1,2,3) in the altered array. However if the array contains just one number, or sets of consecutive numbers 3 or more(1,2,3,5,6,7,8) then it fails with an out of bounds exception in the declaration of the while loop: while(list.get(end) == list.get(end-1)+1). Also I notice that it crashes on 2,4,5 but not 2,4,5,6(which it prints as 0,,4-6). Either way the first digit(in this case a 2)is always printed out as a 0.

Comment: Good catch! I made a couple iteration errors, and was saving the index not the list item. Fixed and tested, it should work now.

Comment: I tried the changes. And you were right! It's almost working perfect! The only thing I'm finding is that if the consecutive numbers come at the end of the array it prints them without the hyphen. So for example if I do 1,2,3,8,9,10 it will print 1-3,8,9,10. But if I do 1,2,3,8,9,10,11 it prints everything correctly 1-3,8-11. Outside of that It's perfect!!!! :-)

Comment: WHOOPS! another offbyOne error.... Changing the code... 
Basically my if needs to be if(i<list.size()-2)